# How to find the exact widget details

Tags: widgets

I imported the blog to my self-hosted WP. I also found the theme I was using, downloaded and installed it.
I don't see all the widgets that are available in my Wordpress.com dashboard.

I can search for widgets e.g. Twitter but it gives me like 1000 results. I want exactly the one I have on my curren wordpress.com blog.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the [JetPack](http://jetpack.me/) plugin, which includes several of the .com features for your stand-alone blog. There's a Twitter widget in there that might be the one you were using.

Comment: Thanks. I got that but it is asking me to connect to my wordpress account and asking for some authorization. You know what's that required for? Is it owned by WP or by some other company?

Comment: @oms - much probably wordpress.com forums may offer more indepth info. I suppose you'll have to copy the config by hand. About the Company and the Free Software: http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/

Comment: @oms JetPack is written and maintained by Automattic, the same company that runs the WordPress.com service. The fact that you have to authenticate to a wordpress.com account even if you aren't using modules that specifically need it is a matter of some debate. But if there are pieces in there you really want to use, it's probably not too big a deal.